# Insert & Delete tags with mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, tags

I have an issue when I try to open a page where there a input tags to insert into the DB... when I open the page the data is deleted and is inserted a blank one with 0 in the ID.. and the another issue is that always show me the word "array" and don't show the data ... can you help me with this problem?

here is the DB structure, my previous data insert (in phpMyAdmin), image with how see it the form in the page and the result when I open the page (with id_pag = 1) in the DB the data changed :
![tags][1]

Here is the form with the code:

---

**EDITED WITH NEW CODE**

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/connection.php');
$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
    try{
    $tags = is_array($_POST['tags'])
    ? implode(', ', $_POST['tags'])
    : $_POST['tags'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO TAGS (tags,id_pag) 
    VALUES (:tags,:id_pag)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':tags', $tags);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_pag', $_POST['id_pag']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Registro ingresado correctamente.';                               
    }
        catch (Exception $e) 
    {
            $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;                
}                           
?>
```

The javascript ajax call (in 'js/custom.js'):

```
$(function(){
    $("#tags").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"assets/tag.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
        dataType:"text",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend:function(){
          $("#loading").show();
        },
        success:function(response){
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $("#loading").hide();
        } 
      })
      return false;
   });
});
```

The form:

```
<?php
    try { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select tags,id_pag from TAGS where id_pag = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $tags = $row['tags'];
        $id_pag = $row['id_pag'];
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    { 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }                                   
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="tags" id="tags" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Palabras clave</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="tags_1" type="text" class="form-control tags" name="tags[]" value="<?php echo $tags; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control tags" name="id_pag" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Grabar</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="assets/img/ajax_loader.gif" /></div>
```

***now I can see the data but when I try to save new tags the ajax call is empty, dont sent nothing..the ajax-loader.gif is showed but not insert nothing in DB***

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). PDO provides mechanisms against this, and you're not using ANY of them. As for your `Array` problem, `$foo = array(); echo $foo;` is the cause of it - you're trying to output an array in a string context.

Comment: You **must** use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) for any and all user data, especially `$_POST` parameters. What you're doing here completely bypasses the PDO data placeholder system and that's extremely bad.

Comment: @tadman and Marc B , thank you for your tutorials..I change the code and now I see the data in DB, but when I try to save new tags the ajax call is empty...can you help me with this

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? What's the contents of the call?

Comment: @tadman, I have in my desktop Fiddler2 with this software I see if the ajax call sent the data to the DB(in the file with the table TAGS), and I see that only send the time and not the tags[] input data and id_pag input data which is hidden in the form with id "tags"

Comment: It might help if you amend your question to include a sample of this JSON data to make it clear what's missing. Also remove things like the screenshot that aren't really relevant and just takes up space.

Comment: @tadman sorry for my late respond, now I delete the old code and the image..here is the form, the javascript and the DB connection to insert in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question:

The code:

```
<?php 
    require_once("connection.php");
    $action = isset( $_POST["action"] ) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
    if($action == "update_tag"){
        try{
            $tags = is_array($_POST['tags'])
            ? implode(', ', $_POST['tags'])
            : $_POST['tags'];
            $sql = 'UPDATE TAGS SET 
            tags = :tags, 
            id_pag = :id_pag 
            WHERE id_tags= :id_tags';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':tags', $tags, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_pag', $_POST['id_pag'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_tags', $_POST['id_tags'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Configuracion actualizado correctamente.";
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

The form:

```
<?php 
    try { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select id_tags, tags, id_pag from TAGS where id_pag = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id_tags = $row['id_tags'];
        $tags = $row['tags'];
        $id_pag = $row['id_pag'];
        }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    } 
?>
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" name="tags_save" id="tags_save" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?php echo $translate->__('Keywords'); ?></label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="tags_1" type="text" class="form-control tags" name="tags[]" value="<?php echo $tags; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id_pag" value="1" id="id_pag"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id_tags" value="<?php echo $id_tags; ?>" id="id_tags"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="col-sd-offset-3 col-md-3">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_tag" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $translate->__('Save'); ?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="loading_tag" style="display:none;"><img src="assets/img/ajax_loader.gif" /></div>
```

The javascript ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tags_save").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"includes/tag.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
            dataType:"text",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
                $("#loading_tag").show();
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#responds").append(response);
                $("#loading_tag").hide();
            } 
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now I can update and delete the tags! but **The only thing I don't know is how create it when is a new page with no tags in it..**